# What is the easiest method to add individual numbers in a string using javascript

Tags: javascript, sum

I have some logic within an app that generating strings like the following:

```
"001"
"021"
"031"
```

I want to take the single string and split this and add the numbers in a basic efficient manner.

e.g for the second string above
`021` - desired outcome would be split this to make the sum `0 + 2 + 1 = 3` - how do I split the string by each number using vanilla javascript?

Comment: If the string is 000011111011 should the splitting be like `000` `011` `111` `011` or `11111` and `11`

Comment: @Zabs are you wanting to keep base 8 or convert to base 10?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var array = "0123456";
var result = array.split("").reduce((acc, cur) => {return (+acc) + (+cur);},0);
console.log(result);
```

As Bucket said in the comments, this will split the string up into characters, then use `array.reduce()` to merge all the characters into one value by using an arrow function that converts them to numbers and sums them.

Comment: perfect @Feathercrown - this is what I was looking for :)

Comment: @Zabs Glad to hear I could help!

Comment: Just to explain some of the "isms" here, `split()` returns an array of strings separated by the given delimiter; `reduce()` executes the given function on each of the array's members and outputs a single value; `(...) -> {...}` is arrow notation for `function(...) {...}`; and the `+` unary operator converts the value to a numeric.

Comment: Good code. It can be reduced even more to: `array.split("").reduce((cur, acc) =>+cur+ +acc,0);`

Comment: The accumulator (the argument you call "cur") is set to the number zero and remains a number so you don't need to convert it at all.

Comment: @James Better safe than sorry. Although I did switch `acc` and `cur` accidentally, you're right-- fixed now.

Comment: Certainly makes it safer if you struggle to remember the argument order (which I do) - good enough.

Comment: Thanks @Bucket-- I was waiting for the customary day of waiting to accept an answer, but forgot to notify now that it has passed and they have seemingly forgotten.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var str = "021";
    var a = str.split(""); // converts the string into an array
    
    var result = a.reduce((i, n) => {
        return Number(i)+ Number(n)
    },0); 
    
    console.log(result)
    //result = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var result = 0;
var second = "021";
var arr = second.split("");

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    result = +arr[i] + result;

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Vanilla Javascript *is* plain Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably as efficient as you can possible make it, but it does not do any input validation:

```
var input = "0021031";
var zeroCode = "0".charCodeAt(0);

function sum(input) {
  var result = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; ++i) {
    result += input.charCodeAt(i) - zeroCode;
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(sum(input))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function mathAdd(s) {
  // take input and split it by ''
  // use a as the accumulator
  // use v as the value
  // add the value to the accumulator and start at 0
  // return the value
  return String(s).split('').reduce((a, v) => a + parseInt(v, 10), 0);
}

console.log(mathAdd("001"));
console.log(mathAdd("021"));
console.log(mathAdd("031"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Adding Numbers in a String :- 
function addNum(nums) {
    let newnums = nums.split(',').map(Number);
    sum = 0;
    for(i=0; i<newnums.length; i++) {
        sum = sum + newnums[i];
    } return sum;
}
console.log(addNum("1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7"))
```